# Is there a way to name vim folds?

Tags: vim, fold

Is there a way to name vim folds?

I understand that by using comments or the foldtext method you can effectively name folds. However, I'm writing an Azure Resource Manager template which is pure JSON, so it doesn't allow comments.

Comment: It looks like this is possible with the foldtext() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fold "name" can be set via the foldtext option. This is what I've done for the for the ARM template:

```
set foldtext=ARMFoldText()

function! ARMFoldText()
" Between foldstart and foldend, return the line that has the name
let i = v:foldstart + 1
while i < v:foldend
  let foldName = getline(i)
  if foldName =~# '^\s*"name":'
    break
  endif
  let i += 1
endwhile
"if foldlevel = 2 return foldName else return foldtext
if foldlevel(v:foldstart) == 2
  return foldName
else
  return foldtext()
endif
endfunction
```

This is what it looks like with my custom fold expression:

```
  1 {
  2   "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  3   "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  4 +-- 24 lines: "variables": {---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 28 +-- 16 lines: "parameters": {--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 44   "resources": {
 45    "name": "[variables('vnet-name')]",-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 66       "name": "[variables(ip-public-name)]",--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 75       "name": "[variables('lb-web-01')]",--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
115       "name": "[variables('nic-01-name')]",------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
148       "name": "[variables('sg-app-01')]",--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
172       "name": "[variables('sg-web-01')]",-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

There's also plenty of other examples to work from. The ones that I referenced were the following:

http://dhruvasagar.com/2013/03/28/vim-better-foldtext
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Customize_text_for_closed_folds